# How to share user based data in Loopback?

Tags: scope, access-token, loopbackjs

I want to share data from a user. It's not that easy because I have some requirements for the data access:

- the data should be limited in time
- just specific data (models) should be accessible
- Shared data should be read-only

After some investigation I found out that the access token can fulfill my requirements. However I've got some problems with the 'scopes' property.

Example: As a logged-in user I create an access token by POST method. The body of the POST method is as follow:

`{
 "ttl": 60,
 "scopes":["read:profile"] 
}`

As response I got:

`{
 "id": "kAENvrotSr9wUwmZIBTH71kKZpaUthqsSkFpksROFjFPkS3gHgLHzDC6zh1g0i9r",
 "ttl": 60,
 "scopes": ["profile"],
 "created": "2018-12-15T11:45:46.000Z",
 "userId": 2
}`

Unfortunately by executing GET '[...]/user/1/profiles' with the received access token I got Error 401: "Authorization Required".

Additional information: When I remove the scope field in the access token creating process, I'm supposed to access '[...]/user/1/profiles'. I guess I'm using the wrong syntax.

What I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance!